# Borrowed value does not live long enough - string slice into HashMap

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I can't get my function to be compiled. It always complains about the borrowed value not living long enough. I already switched order of the HashMap with the string slices because I thought destruction order would affect that the HashMap would live one step longer than the string slices put in. But even after the change it still does not work:

**CODE**

```
fn lyrics_more_bottles(song_template:&mut String, number:i32){
    let mut start_bottles:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
    let mut remaining_num:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
    let mut template_partials:HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();

    template_partials.insert("start", start_bottles);
    template_partials.insert("repeat", start_bottles);
    template_partials.insert("remaining", remaining_num);
    template_partials.insert("message", "Take one down and pass it around");

    resolve_template(song_template, template_partials);
}
```

ERROR_MSG:

```
lib.rs:45:34: 45:63 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
lib.rs:45     let mut start_bottles:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:45:34: 45:63 note: in this expansion of format! (defined in <std macros>)
lib.rs:45:73: 55:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 45:72...
lib.rs:45     let mut start_bottles:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
lib.rs:46     let mut remaining_num:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
lib.rs:47     let mut template_partials:HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
lib.rs:48 
lib.rs:49     template_partials.insert("start", start_bottles);
lib.rs:50     template_partials.insert("repeat", start_bottles);
          ...
lib.rs:45:5: 45:73 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 45:4
lib.rs:45     let mut start_bottles:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:45:5: 45:73 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
lib.rs:45     let mut start_bottles:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:46:34: 46:63 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
lib.rs:46     let mut remaining_num:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:46:34: 46:63 note: in this expansion of format! (defined in <std macros>)
lib.rs:46:73: 55:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 46:72...
lib.rs:46     let mut remaining_num:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
lib.rs:47     let mut template_partials:HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
lib.rs:48 
lib.rs:49     template_partials.insert("start", start_bottles);
lib.rs:50     template_partials.insert("repeat", start_bottles);
lib.rs:51     template_partials.insert("remaining", remaining_num);
          ...
lib.rs:46:5: 46:73 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 46:4
lib.rs:46     let mut remaining_num:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lib.rs:46:5: 46:73 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
lib.rs:46     let mut remaining_num:&str = format!("{} bottles", number).as_str();
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings needs an owner:

```
fn lyrics_more_bottles(song_template:&mut String, number:i32){
    let mut start_bottles = format!("{} bottles", number); // own them as `String`
    let mut remaining_num = format!("{} bottles", number);
    let mut template_partials:HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();

    template_partials.insert("start", &start_bottles); // &String -> &str is implicit
    template_partials.insert("repeat", &start_bottles);
    template_partials.insert("remaining", &remaining_num);
    template_partials.insert("message", "Take one down and pass it around");

    resolve_template(song_template, template_partials);
}
```